# How to move IFRAME into a DIV?

Tags: html, css, iframe

There is a HTML content which users can freely edit. Thats OK, but I have to move all IFRAME into a DIV. Im trying with this:

```
$('#rolunk_content iframe').html ('<div>1' + $('#rolunk_content iframe').html() + '2</div>');
```

but that has no effect.

EDIT: a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nE3jG/

Comment: Could you write some example codes in HTML?

Answer (score 3):

That's because your code is trying to set the `innerHTML` of an `iframe`, which obviously won't work... And the rest of your logic is wrong too...

Try:

```
$("#rolunk_content iframe").each(function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        rel = this.nextSibling, par = this.parentNode;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
    div.appendChild(this); // the iframe
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2"));
    par.insertBefore(div,rel);
});
```

[Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) may be lengthier to write, but it is more reliable in terms of doing what you expect it to do ;)

Comment: that killed the IFRAME

Comment: "Killed" it? How do you mean? All this does is attach it to a new p- ooooh, right, browsers don't like it when you do that. Sorry, no real fix there. That's a limitation of browsers.

Comment: Aha, okay, the problem was that there was no `nextSibling` XD Updated code to reflect that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move `IFRAME` into a `DIV`, you can use jQuery `.append()` API .

```
 $("#newdiv").append($("#rolunk_content iframe"));
```

Your code could go like this:

```
<div id="rolunk_content">
    <p><iframe src="...."  width="200" height="200"></iframe></p>
</div>
<input id="d" type="button">
<hr>
<div id="newdiv">Your IFRAME will be moved here.</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$('#d').click(function() {
    $("#newdiv").append($("#rolunk_content iframe"));
});
```

The Fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2HrA4/

And the document of jQuery `.append()` is here:
https://api.jquery.com/append/